# there is way to show my avatar png ? because it doesnt work like my example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

is there way to show my avatar png ?because it doesnt work like my example
i try to show my jpg image but it doesnt work for me and i dont know why .
it show me jus an unrounded grey shape right now and i want a rounded shape jpg.
what is my mistake ?

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform ,Image } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import HeaderButton from "../components/HeaderButton";
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';


const OrderInformationScreen = props => {
    return(
        <View
        style={{
        //   height: 150,
        //   backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <Avatar
          size='large'
        //    overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#00BFFF' }}
           containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
          activeOpacity={0.2}
          rounded
        ImageSource={require('../assets/up.png')}  style={{height: 120, width: 120, borderRdius: 60 }}
        />
        <View>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>yes</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
    };

export default OrderInformationScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Image` from React Native itself.

```
<View style={{ width: 120, height: 120, borderRadius: 60 }} />
   <Image source={require('../assets/up.png')} resizeMode={'cover'} style={{ width: 120, height: 120 }}/>
</View>
```